# Disable Jinja template caching for certain filter

Tags: jinja2

We have a custom Jinja filter that we use for creating cache busting URL for our Javascript and CSS resources. We now noticed that in our production environment the final, compiled templates get cached. This results in a problem since our template filter sometimes doesn't create a new URL (i.e. when the template wasn't changed but the Javascript was).

Is there a way to force Jinja to reevaluate a certain filter every time and don't cache the result?

**Edit 1**: We are using constant inputs (name of the file) to the filter.

Answer (score 10):

After lots of Googling, I finally found the real solution to this. Jinja has a special helper called [pass_context](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.pass_context) that you can use to decorate your function with to make your filter context-aware (and context-dependent). The Jinja bytecode cache will not cache this computed value, even when a constant is passed as input.

In your filter in Python:

```python
from jinja2 import pass_context

@pass_context
def asset_url(context, url):
    return some_url_thing(url)
```

In your template:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'styles.css' | asset_url }}" />
```

Note: `pass_context` used to be called `contextfilter` in versions before 3.0.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to disable caching of the result of a particular filter: it's by *not* using a constant input, e.g. by exposing a *random source* as a global variable.

```
# Expose to Jinja
from random import random as RANDOM
```

And in the templates

```
{{ RANDOM() | eval_this_filter_every_time }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The caching behaviour of Jinja2 can be configured using the `cache_size` setting: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.Environment

However, this only caches the templates itself. As long as the input for a filter is variable the output will be variable too.

So... how are you using the filter? Can you post the part of the template and the filter that is getting cached?

Comment: Yes, we are using a constant input values (the name of the file we want to cachebust).

Comment: I have a custom filter called `datetimeformat` which formats the passed datetime. I added a shortcut to it, that when `'now' | datetimeformat` is used, it would put the current time. And found out that it doesn't change...

Comment: @warvariuc: it would depend on how you get `'now'`. If that is properly constructed it should work but it's easy to accidentally make the date static and therefore break all changes.

Comment: I mean a literally using `'now' | datetimeformat` -- passing string `"now"` and in the filter treating this case separately putting the current time. I ended passing `now` function which is equal to `datetime.datetime.utcnow`, but that's what just an example of a case when a constant is passed to a filter breaking the logic.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is:

On your flask server script do this:

```
from time import ctime
```

In your app.route() function,

in the return line add:

```
time=ctime()
```

for example:

```
return render_template('signup', error = error, time = ctime())
```

In the html reference for your css file(if using jinja2) add:

```
?{{time}}
```

at the end of your reference line.

That shoud look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/base.css')}}?{{time}}">
```

Worked pretty good for me and the browser stopped caching.

I hope it helps!

Cheers!

-Nelio