# Jinja2 - filter not rendering on subsequent page reloads (in Flask)

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2

I've unsuccessfully spent several hours trying to figure this out.
I am trying to simply register a `jinja2 filter` in a `Flask` app, but for whatever reason the `filter` only works on the first page load after the server has started. On all subsequent requests the filter will not render as expected.

Here is what I have:

- inside a helper `class` I have a simple `static method` that generates a token used in a `HTML` `data` attribute:

  ```
  @staticmethod
  def anti_cache_token(switch):
      if switch:
          return time.time()
      else:
          return None
  ```
- inside the file where I instantiate the `Flask` app I register this this method as a `filter` in the `jinja_env`:

  ```
  app.jinja_env.filters['anti_cache_token'] = Helpers.anti_cache_token
  ```
- finally, I call the `filter` in my `template` like this:

  ```
  {{ true | anti_cache_token }}
  ```

This is the outcome:

- first time when I run the `Flask` built-in `server` the filter renders correctly the `time.time()` result.
- after I reload the page, or open it in another browser, the result remains the same, although it should change. **(?)**

It is the first time I am using `jinja2` and I am clearly missing something here. I would really appreciate your help with this one.

---

### Edit:

[This answer is helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305519/calling-template-filter-function-in-flask-only-once) in understanding why this is happening. However, my question is how can I prevent the caching from happening.

@davidsm can you please share any ideas on how to overcome this? You've rushed to closing it without a substantiated answer...

---

### Alternative answer:

For those who still need help with this, you can find a possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968378/5252007